# Heroku plugins:install fails for treasure data cli (td)

Tags: ruby, heroku

I tried to install Treasure Data heroku cli plugin (td) as described in [heroku devcenter](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/treasure-data) using

```
$ heroku plugins:install https://github.com/treasure-data/heroku-td.git
```

command but it failed with the following error message:

```
Installing heroku-td... failed
 !    Unable to load plugin heroku-td.
 !    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com


    Error:       'td' gem is missing.  Please install td: gem install td (RuntimeError)
    Backtrace:   /home/istvan/.heroku/plugins/heroku-td/init.rb:4:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
                 /home/istvan/.heroku/plugins/heroku-td/init.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/plugin.rb:66:in `load'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/plugin.rb:66:in `load_plugin'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/plugins.rb:46:in `block in install'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/helpers.rb:232:in `action'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command/plugins.rb:44:in `install'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/command.rb:193:in `run'
                 /usr/local/heroku/lib/heroku/cli.rb:25:in `start'
                 /usr/bin/heroku:26:in `<main>'

    Command:     heroku plugins:install https://github.com/treasure-data/heroku-td.git
    Plugins:     heroku-td
    Version:     heroku-toolbelt/2.30.3 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3
```

I have already installed td on my local machine using

```
$ gem install td
```

See gem list output:

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.5)
fluent-logger (0.4.3)
hirb (0.7.0)
json (1.7.5)
msgpack (0.4.7)
rake (0.9.2.2)
rubygems-bundler (1.0.6)
rvm (1.11.3.5)
td (0.10.38)
td-client (0.8.22)
td-logger (0.3.14)
thor (0.16.0)
yajl-ruby (1.1.0)
```

And in fact, td command works on my local machine:

```
$ td
usage: td [options] COMMAND [args]
```

This is my heroku version and ruby version:

```
$ heroku -v
heroku-toolbelt/2.30.3 (i686-linux) ruby/1.9.3

$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.2p320 (2012-04-20 revision 35421) [i686-linux]
```

Do you have any suggestions regarding what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

While you have the `td` gem installed, it is unavailable to the `heroku` command provided by the Heroku Toolbelt.

@geemus describes the problem in a GitHub issue: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/568

Try installing the TD heroku plugin via the `heroku` gem and *not* with the Toolbelt. I'm not positive, but try

- Adding `heroku` to your Gemfile
- `bundle install`
- Run `bundle exec heroku plugins:install ...`

There is an [outstanding issue](https://github.com/treasure-data/heroku-td/issues/1) on the TD plugin for Toolbelt compatibility.